# Notepad++ "Find in files" not searching in

Tags: html, search, notepad++

I'm doing a search for a term "BasePlugins" in a directory using the "Find in Files" feature of Notepad++.  If I use Windows XP's search function in this directory, it will find several HTML files with the term "BasePlugins" inside.  However, Notepad++ did not find these instances of the term "BasePlugins" in these HTML files, is there a reason for this?  I had it set to not care about matching case and to search subfolders, but it still wouldn't find the HTML files...

Comment: belongs in super user :), maybe you will have more luck there, i know i did

Answer (score 6):

Not really a developer question.

I just tried it on my notepad++ 5.6.8(unicode). Works fine.

Just remember to check the checkbox for in ***all-subfolders***. Also remember to point the ***directory*** into the right place. I also put `*.*` in the filter field.

Comment: Beat me to it.  I was also going to add that he should try unticking the "match case" and "match whole word only" boxes, if he's still not finding anything...

Answer (score 4):

I found that the results where shown in a window which was minimized. draging the bar solved the issue. Before dragging the bar this is what it saw:
[image: Before dragging bar]
Afterwards a list of results where visible:
[image: After dragging bar]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Kyle that's exactly it!  It says "Press Enter" to cancel, but I didn't realize hitting "OK" would cancel it...I think I hit "OK" thinking I should hit "OK" to see the results of the search (since there's no progress bar I didn't know the search was ongoing, it was taking a long time).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't comment on my original question above as I wasn't registered when I wrote it, and I don't have enough points to comment on the above answers, so I have to post these follow-up details as an answer...

If I use "Find in Files," with "in all sub-folders" selected, and with the "match whole word" and "match case" boxes unchecked, and I search for the term "baseplugin" in the path

C:\Program Files\ElectroServer_4_0_6\documentation\server\extension,

I get the result "24 hits in 6 files." However if I do the same exact thing for the path C:\Program Files\ElectroServer_4_0_6\documentation, I get the result "0 hits in 0 files."

Am I missing something? I figured with "In all sub-folders" checked, the results would be the same whether I was searching C:\Program Files\ElectroServer_4_0_6\documentation\server\extension or C:\Program Files\ElectroServer_4_0_6\documentation

The folder structure and contents I am searching come from: https://www.electro-server.com/downloads/builds/ElectroServer_4_0_6_Windows.exe. Thanks for any insight into why this is happening/if I'm missing something, thanks...

Comment: "whole word" checkbox you tried helped me.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Uninstall Notepad++

2 - Reinstall Notepad++ and CHECK "DON'T USE %APPDATA%"

This has worked for me.